# Laravel Boilerplate Accessing Frontend page from Backend

Tags: php, laravel, routes, boilerplate

In Laravel boilerplate, how could we accessing frontend page while logged in at backend environment?

I've put this routes at frontend access.php, but while putting it at access.php in backend, it doesn't load properly

`Route::get('test', 'LoginController@showTestForm')->name('test');`

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default namespace in route.php file is related to Controller directory (if not specifically changed by application developer). Try this:

```
Route::get('test', 'Frontend\Auth\LoginController@showTestForm')->name('test');
```

Comment: Yes, it does work when I try to put above code in global route. Laravel Boilerplate global route called `\routes\web.php`. Thanks :)

Comment: #StackOverflowReadyToHelp